# Отсутствие и наличие ошибки в одном и том же коде: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore'

Tags: javascript, база-данных, reactjs, indexeddb

Вылетает ошибка : Unhandled Rejection (DataError): Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': Evaluating the object store's key path did not yield a value.

Проблема в том, что у коллеги с этим же самым кодом (из одного репозитория в гите) этой ошибки нет, код идентичный, идей у меня нет.

ошибка вылезает на строчке `db.fieldsets.put()` возможно проблема в индексе, но опять же, такой же код работает на компьютере в 2 метрах от меня, а на моём не работает.
на домашнем сегодня попробую, кто знает, но кажется не работает.

```
dexie_db.js:

import Dexie from 'dexie';
const db = new Dexie('fieldsets');
db.version(1).stores({
         fieldsets:'++id, user',

});
export default db;

import * as global from '../../global';
import getFields from './field-defs';
import db from '../../dexie_DB'

let g_fieldsets = [];

async function readFieldsets(fsetKey){
fsetKey = fsetKey+'_offers'
let res;
const userSets = await db.fieldsets.get(fsetKey);
if(!userSets || userSets.v !== 
process.env.REACT_APP_OFFERS_FIELDSET_VERSION){
    const defaultSets = [{
        name: 'Все поля',
        favourite: true,
        data:getFields().map((it,i)=>({
                name:it.name,
                hidden: false,}))
    },];
    res = defaultSets
    console.log(fsetKey,defaultSets)
    console.log('1')
    console.log(db)
    db.fieldsets.put({
        user: fsetKey,
        v:process.env.REACT_APP_OFFERS_FIELDSET_VERSION,
        data: defaultSets
    })
}else{
    res = userSets.data
}
g_fieldsets = res.map(it=>({
    ...it,
    data:it.data.map(item=>({
        ...item,
        def: getFields().find(def=> item.name===def.name)
    }))
}))
global.events.fieldsetsUpdated.next(null)
}

global.currentUser.subscribe(u=>{
if(u){
    readFieldsets(u.login)
}else{
    g_fieldsets = []
}
})

export function getFieldsets(force){
if(force || !g_fieldsets.length){
    if(!global.currentUser.getValue()){
        return [];
    }
    let _ = (readFieldsets(global.currentUser.getValue().login))
}
return g_fieldsets;
}

export function validate(name, it){
return {
    valid: null,
    msg: null
};
}

export function isEntityValid(it){
if(!it){
    return false
}if(!it.supplierId || !it.supplierId.length){
    return false
}if(!it.amount || it.amount<0){
    return false
}if(!it.offeredPrice || it.offeredPrice<0){
    return false
}
return true;
}
```

Не знаю, в чём дело, может это драйвера, может это какие-то программы, которые запущены в трее, то, что может сломать или починить работу кода.

Comment: некоторые из  возможных причины: 1) Кому-то из вас необходимо сделать `npm install` 2) Кто-то из вас подтягивает код с другого компа по локальной сети, другими словами, в `href` записано не `localhost`, а ip-адрес.

Comment: если install должен починить. то нет, я только буквально заново скачал проект в новую папку и установил, ничего(
на обоих компах запуск идёт на локальной машине, код идентичный, как-то ещё можно подтягивать данные?

Comment: Запуск может быть и на локальной машине, но код (часть кода, отдельный скрипт) может подтягиваться с соседней

Comment: разобрались, что случилось?